# Generate tone with increasing amplitude using pyaudio

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi, signal-processing, pyaudio

I'm trying to generate a tone similar to this that I've created using audacity where the amplitude increases from 0.1 to 1 using pyaudio.

[image]

So far I haven't been successful figured out how to do this in pyaudio. I can generate a sine wave but can't create one with increasing amplitude.

I'm aiming on using a raspberry pi 4 if that helps.

Edit- Here's what I've tried so far. Basically I've tried combining a sine wave with a the first half of a triangle wave.

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import wave
from scipy import signal
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

#amp 5000
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16 
filename = 'test8.wav'
chunk = 1024
channels = 1
sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16
def excitation(freq=60 ,duration=9, amplitude=1, fs=44100):
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    #Sine wave generation
    seconds = duration
    sine = (amplitude*np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(fs*duration)*freq/fs)).astype(np.float32)


    t = np.linspace(0, duration*2, fs*duration)
    triangle = signal.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * (1/(duration*2)) * t)
    ramp = amplitude* 2 *triangle[0:(len(sine))]

    samples = sine + ramp

    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=1,
                rate=fs,
                output=True,
                input = True)

    frames = []  # Initialize array to store frames
    stream.write(samples)


    # Store data in chunks for 3 seconds
    for i in range(0, int(fs / chunk * seconds)):
        data = stream.read(chunk)
        frames.append(data)

    # Stop and close the stream 
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    # Terminate the PortAudio interface
    p.terminate()

    # Save the recorded data as a WAV file
    wf = wave.open(filename, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(channels)
    wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(sample_format))
    wf.setframerate(fs)
    wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    wf.close()

    return 

excitation()
```

Comment: please post the code that you have written so far

Comment: Please share what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you can generate the audio ahead of time, you can simply apply an increasing gain as a multiplier to each sample as a post-processing step.

```
samples = generate_samples()
for i in range(0, len(samples)):
  samples[i] *= i/len(samples)
```

You could also do this in numpy as follows:

```
samples = generate_samples() #returns a np.array
ramp = np.arange(0,1,1/len(samples))
samples *= ramp
```